# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Tags: javascript

calling the below function from html

```
displaySSHCmdResultDiv('12:21:08 up 4 days, 1:37, 3 users, load average: 0.44, 0.46, 0.44')
```

Throws me error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL " in chrome. can any one help me in identifying what the problem is .

Comment: Either it doesn't come from this call (maybe inside the function?), or you forgot to use a semicolon at the end of the function call.

Comment: I am sorry there is error in prob statement if it is being called as displaySSHCmdResultDiv('{{dataItems.respValue}}') the error is thrown. The value of {{dataItems.respValue}} is '12:21:08 up 4 days, 1:37, 3 users, load average: 0.44, 0.46, 0.44'

Answer (score 0):

As per your code function aruguments is 6 and its seprated by comma so you have complete single cot for each srting

```
displaySSHCmdResultDiv('12:21:08 up 4 days','1:37',' 3 users', 'load average: 0.44', '0.46', '0.44');
```